# How to substitute factor variables?

Tags: r

I'm using a data set that has three levels: N, S, and U, which stand for nonsmoker, smoker, and unismoker respectively.

How to do replace U with "Unismoker". The new level would be: N, S, and Unismoker.

Here is what I have tried:
1). `mort_data2$smoker[which(mort_data2$smoker=="U")] = levels("Unismoker")`

2). `levels(mort_data2$smoker)[which(mort_data2$smoker=="U")] = "Unismoker"`

When I use `table(mort_data2$smoker)`, both approaches simply returns

```
N 167
S 170
U 0 (was 181 before)
```

But I want to return the following:

```
N 167
S 170
Unismoker 181
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `levels`.

```
# Example df
a=data.frame(a=c(rep("N",10),rep("S",20),rep("U",30)))
> str(a)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels "N","S","U": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> levels(a$a)
[1] "N" "S" "U"

levels(a$a)[3] = "Unismoker"

> summary(a)
         a     
 N        :10  
 S        :20  
 Unismoker:30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named list with `levels<-` to replace items. You have to specifiy things for each level though, even if they don't change.

```
x <- factor(c("N","S","U"))
levels(x) <- list(N="N",S="S",Unismoker="U")
x
[1] N         S         Unismoker
Levels: N S Unismoker
```